# Create a spinner wheel in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

Hello i am trying to make a spinner wheel in react native using Animatable. Following the example here (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/practical-animations-in-react-native--cms-27567) I was able to rotate a rectangle box. Here is the code!

```
  <Animatable.View
                        ref={animation[0]}
                        style={[styles.box, { backgroundColor: animation[1] }]}
                        animation={animation[0]}
                        iterationCount={"infinite"}>
                        <Text style={styles.box_text}>{animation[0]}</Text>
 </Animatable.View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            padding: 20
        },
        row: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        },
        box: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            backgroundColor: '#ccc'
        },
        box_text: {
            color: '#FFF'
        }
    });
```

But the prob is here we are rotating a box creating using css, Is there a way where i can make my own spinner using html and css and rotate it and stop it according to the business rules?

[image]

Need some directions and suggestions thank you!

Comment: did you make it @Salman Shaykh ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-of-fortune npm package for your purpose.